# Singular value decomposition on a polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, regression, svd

I wrote some python that applies the SVD, then uses SVD to find the best fit for some matrix A. Where A times some "best fit" x is the best solution for a output vector, b.

Using SVD and my made up Ax = b \begin{equation}
A = U \Sigma V^* \: and \: Ax =b\;\; ,
\end{equation}
then (I think)
\begin{equation}
V \Sigma^{-1} U^* (Ax) = V \Sigma^{-1} U^* (b) \;\; ,
\end{equation}
eliminates A, so
\begin{equation}
x = V \Sigma^{-1} U^* (b) \;\; ,
\end{equation}
x is the best fit vector. I hope my equations are correct, I translated it from my code and it's a little bit of python packages and a little my own, but I do get the vector x.

So when I mess around, I make A = column vector that's (0 to 50), and my "b" output vector (0-50)*7. The SVD found the best fit vector x = [7]. Makes sense because my equation is f(i) = 7*i

When I make A with two dimensions, both (o to 50), and my output b = (0 to 50)*7 + (0 to 50)*4. My best fit vector is [7,4]. Sovles the for x correclty because f(i,j) = 7*i + 4*j.

I then make A with three dimensions and an output (0 to 50)*7 + (0 to 50)*4 + (0 to 50)^2. The best fit x fails for the function f(i,j,k) = 7*i + 4*j + k^2. Is the method I'm using to find the best fit x, only work for linear inputs? Is there a way to use this best fit method solution for polynomials?

Comment: Aren't you just computing $x=A^{-1}b$ ?

Comment: well my A matrix isn't square

Comment: If I understand it correctly you want to fit the polynomial $ax+bx^2$ with $a=11$ and $b=1$. However, you have actually split the first one into two parts :$a_1 x + a_2 x=$7 x$+$4 x$=a x=11 x$. These are not linearly independent so you have fitting-problem with no unique solution.

Comment: Yes, in my wordy question

Comment: OK. When used in this way you can only fit (robustly) linearly independent quantities such as $ax+bx^2+cx^3...$ Your method will work in such cases. You seem to be on the right track.